# How to redirect to a specific tab if the user get an error in the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

On mobile I have a page with two forms (login and signup). If I push the 'signin tab' I saw the sign in form. The same for signup.

If a user get an error in signup form, (s)he goes back to signin tab. But I want that (s)he stays in signup tab, see the error messages and continue to complete the form.

I thought in two solutions:

1. I put a condition inside class:

```
class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>"
```

2. I use params[:tab] to redirect to a specific tab.

---

How can I implement that?

Obs. I'm using Rails 4.1 and twitter bootstrap for the tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, when signup failes, you can redirect with tab param:

```
redirect_to sign_in_path(tab: :sign_up)
```

And add in your view to signup tab, as you said:

```
class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] == :sign_up %>"
```

sign in tab

```
class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] != :sign_up %>"
```

Comment: But the first time it goes to signin/signup page, I don't have a params[:tab], so both will not have 'active' css class. I'm trying to override the new action in sessions controller from Devise gem to send a parameter tab with the value 'signin'. Is it a good practice?

Comment: yep, it is common way to customize devise.
I've updated answer, If I understood you correctly, you can add conditional class to signin tab too, to achive it's active status.